# Getting an error in Scapy 3.0 when using RadioTap, which is working fine in Scapy 2.4

Tags: python, scapy

I am just trying to create a packet in scapy which starts with eg

`packet = RadioTap()/Dot11()/Dot11ACK()`

`packet.show()` gives me this error.
I am not able to send any packets without RadioTap field.

```
###[ RadioTap dummy ]###

      version   = 0
      pad       = 0
      len       = None
      present   =
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 851, in show
    if isinstance(f, ConditionalField) and not f._evalcond(self):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 144, in _evalcond
    return self.cond(pkt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/layers/dot11.py", line 130, in <lambda>
    ConditionalField(LELongField('tsft', 0), lambda pkt: pkt.getdictval('present')['TSFT']),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 186, in getdictval
    return fld.i2dict(self, v)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 919, in i2dict
    if x & 1:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: What are you using scapy3 (do you mean kamene?) for, that doesn't work in mainline Scapy?

Comment: I am using scapy version 3.0 for python 3.6.  Initially I used scapy 2.4 version where all the packet manipulating functions were working fine. When I switched to the newer version the RadioTap() function was giving me this error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing (yet) as "Scapy version 3.0". A fork of Scapy, initially abusively named "Scapy3k" or "Scapy for Python3" by his author (leading to a lot of confusion, as you can see) has existed. It has been finally recently renamed as "Kamene", after endless conversations between Scapy's maintainers, Kamene's author, and some distributions maintainers.

The code you are using with Python 3 here is hence probably not Scapy, but Kamene. To be clear, when you have moved to Kamene, believing you were upgrading Scapy, you have actually switched to a software that has received a very limited number of upgrades (bugfixes, new functionalities) than the actual Scapy.

The same codebase for Scapy works with both Python 2.7 and 3.x. So by upgrading to Scapy v. 2.4.0 you should be able to run your code with both Python version (and, hopefully, get the same results). If you are not getting the same results, please [open an issue](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/new)!

Comment: Thanks for the info, yeah the code runs fine for both python 2.7 and python3.